# using a list of parameters in NSum

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, summation

I am trying to make a function that uses NSum, that takes a list of parameters. But NSum doesn't appear to play nicely with lists. A minimum working example is:

```
In:=
myParams = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
mySummandij[i_, j_, paramlist_] := (i^2 + j^2)*paramlist
mySum[paramlist_] :=  NSum[mySummandij[i, j, paramlist], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]
mySum[myParams]
```

This throws an error

```
Out:=
NSum: Summand (or its derivative) mySummandij[i,j,{0.1,0.2,0.3}] is not numerical at point j = 1.
NSum: Summand (or its derivative) mySummandij[i,j,{0.1,0.2,0.3}] is not numerical at point j = 1.`.
NSum: Summand (or its derivative) NSum[mySummandij[i,j,{0.1,0.2,0.3}],{j,1,10},{WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision,NSumTerms->15,Method->Automatic,AccuracyGoal->\[Infinity],PrecisionGoal->Automatic,VerifyConvergence->True,Compiled->Automatic,EvaluationMonitor->None,NSumExtraTerms->Automatic,WynnDegree->1}] is not numerical at point i = 1.
General: Further output of NSum::nsnum will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I'm sure that the problem is passing a parameter. Passing a single number is fine:

```
In:=   NSum[mySummandij[i, j, 0.2], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]
Out:=  1540.
```

Finally this isn't a problem if I replace NSum by Sum. But I want to use NSum because my real problem is more complicated and takes many minutes to calculate over the full parameter range when I use Sum.

Can anyone suggest a solution and perhaps give a gentle explanation (at a novice level!) as to why passing a parameter into NSum is forbidden?

Comment: NSum does not a list of arguments (it's unclear to me what it would mean to calculate the sum of a list). If you want a list of sums instead, then you need to Map the function over your list mySummand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this?

```
myParams = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
mySummandij[i_, j_, paramlist_] := (i^2 + j^2)*paramlist
mySum[paramlist_] := 
 NSum[Evaluate[mySummandij[i, j, #]], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}] & /@ 
  paramlist
mySum[myParams]
```

Out:

```
 {770., 1540., 2310.}
```

Comment: Yes this definitely works. I'm not familiar with the syntax though. What is going on with the ```# & /@``` notation?

Comment: @jms547 Take a look at [the Pure Functions portion of this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469), and also [`Slot` (`#`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and [`Map` (`/@`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). In a notebook, you can always highlight a symbol and hit F1 to get help on it.